# Laravel 5.1 named route resolution with sub-domain not working

Tags: php, routes, laravel-5.1

Thanks for any help you can provide. I am 10 days into learning Laravel 5.1 so any suggestions on what I have missed will be greatly appreciated!

I am having an issue with the resolution of named routes in Laravel 5.1. I am building an app that will have a URL in the format of `{organisation}.website.com`, where `{organisation}` is defined at registration of customer.

The code routes perfectly when using sample subdomains, so long as I hardcode the route address (e.g.: `redirect('/home');`), but when I try and route by named routes from Controller (e.g.: `redirect()->route('session.create');`) the routes resolve like this:

`http://%7Borganisation%7D.website.com/home`

My routes look like this:

```
<?php

/**
 * Entity routes - resolves {organisation}.website.com
 */
Route::group([
        'domain' => '{organisation}.' . env('APP_DOMAIN')
    ], function(){

    /*
    |----------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Freely available routes for login, registration, password reset etc
    |----------------------------------------------------------------------
    */
    Route::group([
        'middleware' => 'guest'
    ], function(){

        // Login
        Route::get('login', ['uses' => 'SessionController@create', 'as' => 'session.create']);
        Route::post('login', ['uses' => 'SessionController@store', 'as' => 'session.check']);

    });

    Route::group([
        'namespace' => 'Website',
        'middleware' => ['authorise'],
    ], function(){


    });

    /*
    |-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Potentially secured routes
    |-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    */
    Route::group([
        'middleware' => ['authorise']
    ], function(){

        // Logout and destroy all Auth data
        Route::get('logout', ['uses' => 'SessionController@destroy', 'as' => 'session.destroy']);

    });
});
```

In my Controllers I call the routing like this:

```
return redirect()
    ->route('session.create')
    ->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'))
    ->withErrors([
        'email' => $this->getFailedLoginMessage(),
    ]);
```

and it successfully completes, but with the above URL and 404. If I change to this it works perfectly.

```
return redirect('/home')
    ->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'))
    ->withErrors([
        'email' => $this->getFailedLoginMessage(),
    ]);
```

What have I missed in my organisation sub domain set up to make named routes work? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Got it working. Below is how I fixed the issue, which essentially I had to bind on the fly to the route the slug of the sub-domain. Hope this helps someone!

I first had to pass the `Organisation` class to my controller methods and change the route calls like this:

```
public function destroy(Organisation $organisation)
    {
        Auth::logout();

        return redirect()->route('session.create', ['organisation' => $organisation->slug]);
    }
```